# Skype for Business Android SDK

Tags: android, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

we are developing Andoid kiosk apps. From that kiosk visitor should be able to call specific employee of company. For security reasons we have to avoid invoke Skype for Android App directly.

From the docs I understand that comunication is achieved through anonymous/guest skype meeting.

We would like call directly to someone from Active Directory. Is there any possibility how to log in specific user and use Skype SDK?

Thanks for any suggestions